# How to non index my website page links?

Tags: google, noindex

Google index my worpress site as

mysite.com/page/1

mysite.com/page/2

mysite.com/page/3  etc

I want to non index page links. How to do that?

Comment: Did you Google? Please check this link [Settings Reading Screen](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Reading_Screen)

Comment: check this one http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/3179/43098

Answer (score 0):

WordPress comes with a built-in feature that allows you to instruct search engines not to index your site. All you need to do is visit **Settings » Reading** and check the box next to Search Engine Visibility option.

[image]

When this box is checked, WordPress adds this line to your website’s header:

```
<meta name='robots' content='noindex,follow' />
```

WordPress also modifies your site’s robots.txt file and add these lines to it:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

These lines ask robots (web crawlers) not to index your pages. However, it is totally up to search engines to accept this request or ignore it. Even though most search engines respect this, some page or random image from your site may get indexed.

Comment: OP doesn't want to un-index entire site

Comment: Ok np for specific page and post please read the following link https://yoast.com/wordpress-noindex-specific-posts-and-pages/

Comment: yoast Plugin did the trick. There I can non index Category, tags, page/2 like sub pages. 

Those options are under **titles & metas** 

thank for quick reply